# How background a process to docker

Tags: linux, docker, background-process, gnu-screen, nohup

I am trying to find out how to background a process using nohup or screen when I either attached to the container or ssh to it. It seems the the tty is being closed every time I exit.

I know there is a way to do this with the docker file but I have no interest in that method.

Comment: You could give more details about the command you execute that close this tty?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this [blog post](http://l33t.peopleperhour.com/2015/03/04/why-the-t-docker-flag-should-not-be-used-for-background-processes/), it is better to *not* use -t with docker exec for a background process.

Try:

```
docker exec <yourContainer> sh -c "(echo start);(yourScript &);(echo end)"
```